# Find DataGrid Row by Object

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have an Object:

```
public class Part
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    ......
    public bool isExist;
}
```

I have a list of Parts and data-bind it to a dataGrid (I'm using Ultragrid):

`List<Part> parts = generatePartsList();`

`ultraGrid1.DataSource = parts;`

I also have a button to print all the selected parts.

Now, I want to highlight the corresponding row each time a part is printed.

```
    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (parts == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        ultraGrid1.PerformAction(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.ExitEditMode);
        foreach (Part part in parts)
        {
            if (part.Selected)
            {
                PrintPart(part);
                HightlightPrintedRow(part, ultraGrid1);
            }
```

How can I implement this function?

`HightlightPrintedRow(Part part, UltraGrid ultraGrid1)`

Notice that the parts in the list may have exactly same values in all field, so I cannot find row by values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out by myself.

```
    HightlightPrintedRow(Part part, UltraGrid ultraGrid1)
    {
        foreach (var row in ultraGrid1.Rows)
        {
            if ((Part)row.ListObject == part)
            {
                row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```